# Accept request from one android application only

Tags: java, android, server-side

I want my `server` to respond only to my `application`. Is it possible to discard request of other apps on `server` (from server side)? and what `data` should i pass from the `application` to `server` for verification.

> Server : java (Glassfish server)
>   Client : Android Application

Comment: yes you can set the user-agent filter at server side to ignore request from other sources.

Comment: thanks for the reply... can u tell me how can i achieve that?

Comment: You can filter by criteria such as user agent, custom header or a token in the request. But this won't be a guarantee since other clients could be modified/written to send the same data. So take whatever you use for recognition as a hint but do not rely on it for anything security related.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The package name of the android app uniquely identifies it. You can use it as a parameter to uniquely identify the app.

Moreover, you can also generate a registration key and assign it to every node(Mobile Device) at the time of sign Up.The sign Up API would also require a package name parameter to identify the app. Later the server side will expect this registration Key as a parameter for each request sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can put filter on user-agent to ignore the request from unwanted sources.

**Android Side**

We can set custom **user-agent** from android with http client.

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
```

**At your serverside**

you can retrieve **user-agent** from request header and check if it is not equals to "**android**" do not serve the request.